# JQuery in php forms - redirect to success page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm using Jquery for form validation in php form.
I'm not able to redirect to success page after successful form submission kindly help

this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#btnreg").click(function(){

var name = $("#name").val();
var uname = $("#uname").val();
var dept = $("#dept").val();
var ap_no = $("#ap_no").val();
var reg_no = $("#reg_no").val();
var password = $("#pswd").val();
if( name =='' || uname =='' || dept =='' || password =='' || reg_no=='')
    {

      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }   
else if((password.length)<8)
    {
        alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    }
else
    {
        $.post("stud_reg_code.php",{ name: name, uname: uname, password:password ,dept:dept ,ap_no:ap_no ,reg_no:reg_no},
      function(data) {
       if(data=='done')
       {

        window.open('http://localhost/itron7/signup_success.php');

       }
    });
   }

});
});
```

function return data, data value will be 'done' if form is submitted successfully
but the form gets submitted and resets and redirection is not done

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to stop default functionality. Give your form an `id` say `#form` and use `submit` trigger

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var name = $("#name").val();
var uname = $("#uname").val();
var dept = $("#dept").val();
var ap_no = $("#ap_no").val();
var reg_no = $("#reg_no").val();
var password = $("#pswd").val();
if( name =='' || uname =='' || dept =='' || password =='' || reg_no=='')
    {

      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }   
else if((password.length)<8)
    {
        alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    }
else
    {
        $.post("stud_reg_code.php",{ name: name, uname: uname, password:password ,dept:dept ,ap_no:ap_no ,reg_no:reg_no},
      function(data) {
       if(data=='done')
       {

        window.open('http://localhost/itron7/signup_success.php');

       }
    });
   }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com" for redirection, don't forget about using preventDefault()

Comment: by adding preventDefault() submit button is not working

Answer (score 0):

finally resolved by changing redirection code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#btnreg").click(function(){

var name = $("#name").val();
var uname = $("#uname").val();
var dept = $("#dept").val();
var ap_no = $("#ap_no").val();
var reg_no = $("#reg_no").val();
var password = $("#pswd").val();
if( name =='' || uname =='' || dept =='' || password =='' || reg_no=='')
    {

      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }   
else if((password.length)<8)
    {
        alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    }
else
    {
        $.post("stud_reg_code.php",{ name: name, uname: uname, password:password ,dept:dept ,ap_no:ap_no ,reg_no:reg_no},
      function(data) {
       if(data==1)
       {

                        var url = "http://localhost/itron7/signup_success.php";
                        $(location).attr('href',url);

       }
    });
   }

});

});
```